# How do I remove gaps inbetween my rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML & CSS. I told my friend that I would help them with a free website.

I have gaps in between my rows. I am using Bootstrap and I have tried some of the suggestions on here (making a new row class and defining the margin/padding) but I believe it has something to do with the mock images themselves, or the hover effect over the top of them.)

If you need anymore information let me know

```css
/****************************** PAGE CONTENT START***********************/

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

#wrapper.toggled .nav-small {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
    width: 80px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
 top: 0;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
 top:0;
    margin-right: -80px;
}

/************Work Images***************/


.work_image img {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
 padding-top:0;
}


a.darken {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
 padding-top:0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;

}

.imgwrap {
   position: relative;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}

.imgdescription {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30%;
   right: 30%;
   top:43%;
   bottom:43%;
   /**background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);**/
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top:0;
   margin-bottom:0;
   padding-bottom:0;
   padding-top:0;
}
  
.imgwrap:hover .imgdescription {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
}

.row-bottom-margin {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/************Work Images End***************/
```

```html
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
            
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_1.jpeg" alt="image-1">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_2.jpeg" alt="image-2">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_3.jpeg" alt="image-3">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_4.jpeg" alt="image-4">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_1.jpeg" alt="image-1">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="work_image">
                                        <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                                        <img src="images/mockimage_2.jpeg" alt="image-2">
                                        <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
             </div> 
             
        </div>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is it you want to achieve? I can tell you at once that using bootstrap is probably not the smartest way to learn, because that HTML code is horrible, non-semantic, and completely wrong (if that is what it looks like, which is a list of images, which should show when you hover over the links?)

Comment: isn't it cellspacing?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to change `a.darken img` from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`:

```css
/****************************** PAGE CONTENT START***********************/

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

#wrapper.toggled .nav-small {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
    width: 80px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
 top: 0;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
 top:0;
    margin-right: -80px;
}

/************Work Images***************/


.work_image img {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
 padding-top:0;
}


a.darken {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
 padding-top:0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;

}

.imgwrap {
   position: relative;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}

.imgdescription {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30%;
   right: 30%;
   top:43%;
   bottom:43%;
   /**background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);**/
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top:0;
   margin-bottom:0;
   padding-bottom:0;
   padding-top:0;
}
  
.imgwrap:hover .imgdescription {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
}

.row-bottom-margin {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/************Work Images End***************/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-1">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-2">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
          <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-3">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-4">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-bottom-margin">
          <div class="col-sm-6 row-bottom-margin">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-1">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="work_image">
              <a href="#" class="darken imgwrap">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image-2">
                <h1 class="imgdescription">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```